# git ignore folder changes but still sync

Tags: android, eclipse, git, gitignore

I am working on an Android project that I sync with git. I imported Google and Facebook Sdks. I want the push to push the sdks so that they are shared, but not to track all the changes in the cache and such. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `.gitignore`. You can add any number of rules to this file specifying files that git should ignore completely.

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Comment: Thanks! I used: git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file.txt and it does what I need